# Can we upload files to AWS S3 and Google Cloud Storage simultaneously using CarrierWave gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, carrierwave

One of my Model's attachments needs to save files on `AWS S3` and the other Model should save it to `Google Cloud Storage`.

Is this possible using CarrierWave gem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could, as per [this wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Define-different-storage-configuration-for-each-Uploader.). Just configure 2 uploaders, each one for a different provider